# Python: convert matrix to positive semi-definite

Tags: python, matrix, svm, linear-algebra

I'm currently working on kernel methods, and at some point I needed to make a non positive semi-definite matrix (i.e. similarity matrix) into one PSD matrix. 
I tried this approach:

```
def makePSD(mat):
    #make symmetric
    k = (mat+mat.T)/2
    #make PSD
    min_eig = np.min(np.real(linalg.eigvals(mat)))
    e = np.max([0, -min_eig + 1e-4])
    mat = k + e*np.eye(mat.shape[0]);
    return mat
```

but it fails if I test the resulting matrix with the following function:

```
def isPSD(A, tol=1e-8):
    E,V = linalg.eigh(A)
    return np.all(E >= -tol)
```

I also tried the approach suggested in other related question ([How can I calculate the nearest positive semi-definite matrix?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/10939213/how-can-i-calculate-the-nearest-positive-semi-definite-matrix)), but the resulting matrix also failed to pass the isPSD test.

Do you have any suggestions on how to correctly make such transformation correctly?

Answer (score 27, accepted):

First thing I’d say is don’t use `eigh` for testing positive-definiteness, since `eigh` assumes the input is Hermitian. That’s probably why you think the [answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/10940283/500207) you reference isn’t working.

I didn’t like that answer because it had an iteration (and, I couldn’t understand its example), nor the [other answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/18542094/500207) there it doesn’t promise to give you the *best* positive-definite matrix, i.e., the one closest to the input in terms of the Frobenius norm (squared-sum of elements). (I have absolutely no idea what your code in your question is supposed to do.)

I do like this Matlab implementation of Higham’s *1988* paper: https://www.mathworks.com/matlabcentral/fileexchange/42885-nearestspd so I ported it to Python (**edit** updated for Python 3):

```
from numpy import linalg as la
import numpy as np


def nearestPD(A):
    """Find the nearest positive-definite matrix to input

    A Python/Numpy port of John D'Errico's `nearestSPD` MATLAB code [1], which
    credits [2].

    [1] https://www.mathworks.com/matlabcentral/fileexchange/42885-nearestspd

    [2] N.J. Higham, "Computing a nearest symmetric positive semidefinite
    matrix" (1988): https://doi.org/10.1016/0024-3795(88)90223-6
    """

    B = (A + A.T) / 2
    _, s, V = la.svd(B)

    H = np.dot(V.T, np.dot(np.diag(s), V))

    A2 = (B + H) / 2

    A3 = (A2 + A2.T) / 2

    if isPD(A3):
        return A3

    spacing = np.spacing(la.norm(A))
    # The above is different from [1]. It appears that MATLAB's `chol` Cholesky
    # decomposition will accept matrixes with exactly 0-eigenvalue, whereas
    # Numpy's will not. So where [1] uses `eps(mineig)` (where `eps` is Matlab
    # for `np.spacing`), we use the above definition. CAVEAT: our `spacing`
    # will be much larger than [1]'s `eps(mineig)`, since `mineig` is usually on
    # the order of 1e-16, and `eps(1e-16)` is on the order of 1e-34, whereas
    # `spacing` will, for Gaussian random matrixes of small dimension, be on
    # othe order of 1e-16. In practice, both ways converge, as the unit test
    # below suggests.
    I = np.eye(A.shape[0])
    k = 1
    while not isPD(A3):
        mineig = np.min(np.real(la.eigvals(A3)))
        A3 += I * (-mineig * k**2 + spacing)
        k += 1

    return A3


def isPD(B):
    """Returns true when input is positive-definite, via Cholesky"""
    try:
        _ = la.cholesky(B)
        return True
    except la.LinAlgError:
        return False


if __name__ == '__main__':
    import numpy as np
    for i in range(10):
        for j in range(2, 100):
            A = np.random.randn(j, j)
            B = nearestPD(A)
            assert (isPD(B))
    print('unit test passed!')
```

In addition to just finding the nearest positive-definite matrix, the above library includes `isPD` which uses the Cholesky decomposition to determine whether a matrix is positive-definite. This way, you don’t need any tolerances—any function that wants a positive-definite will run Cholesky on it, so it’s the absolute best way to determine positive-definiteness.

It also has a Monte Carlo-based unit test at the end. If you put this in `posdef.py` and run `python posdef.py`, it’ll run a unit-test that passes in ~a second on my laptop. Then in your code you can `import posdef` and call `posdef.nearestPD` or `posdef.isPD`.

The code is also in a [Gist](https://gist.github.com/fasiha/fdb5cec2054e6f1c6ae35476045a0bbd) if you do that.

Comment: question is about converting a matrix to positive semi-definite matrix, but answer is about converting to positive-definite matrix as far as I understand. Am I missing something?

Comment: You are right, this function only returns positive-definite matrixes, it's possible that there are positive semi-definite matrixes that are better, but the paper only talks about postiive-definite.

Answer (score 2):

I know this thread is kinda old, but just wanted to say that the question linked by @user1231818 now has a satisfactory answer, at least in the cases I've tested: https://stackoverflow.com/a/63131250/4733085

I'm leaving here the code, but for more details just follow the link:

```py
import numpy as np

def get_near_psd(A):
    C = (A + A.T)/2
    eigval, eigvec = np.linalg.eig(C)
    eigval[eigval < 0] = 0

    return eigvec.dot(np.diag(eigval)).dot(eigvec.T)
```

Comment: This will certainly give you *a* PSD matrix but isn’t necessarily “close” to the original. But if `A` is mostly symmetric, and you don’t need the “best”, this can do in a pinch.

Comment: Yes, in my case `A` is mostly symmetric. The thing is that for the cases I tried (and I tried quite a few) all the other methods gave me quite different matrices, whereas this simple method was the "closest". And the differences were very obvious to me. I'm not sure why, though. Maybe I only tried with too much simple matrices (mostly 2 x 2 in my case) and the other methods could be better for higher dimensions or other cases.

Comment: Ah I can see that happening: the algorithm in my answer minimizes the Frobenius norm between the input and output (the sum of the squares of all the element-wise differences), so it might return a matrix that look visually different than the input because it's trying to spread that error norm between all the elements of the matrix. Hmm, though I'm not sure how often that happens when you zero negative eigenvalues. Sorry for bugging you after so much time since you posted, thanks for responding!

Answer (score 1):

Just in case someone else faces the same problem.
The two methods explained above by @tjiagoM and @Ahmed Fasih are equivalent and should both give the same psd matrix that minimizes the Frobenius norm.
In equations (2.1) and (2.2) of the paper

```
'''
[2] N.J. Higham, "Computing a nearest symmetric positive semidefinite
matrix" (1988): https://doi.org/10.1016/0024-3795(88)90223-6
'''
```

linked in the answer of Ahmed, the calculation method used by tjiagoM is described and actually referred to as the preferred way of computing the closest psd matrix.