# Getting complex coefficients in nearest SPD matrices

Tags: python, numpy, matrix

I am writing a python 3.7 program and I need to get symmetric positive-definite matrices.

I used this code to get the nearest SPD (all eigenvalues have to be > 0) :

[Python: convert matrix to positive semi-definite](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/43238173/python-convert-matrix-to-positive-semi-definite?noredirect=1&lq=1)

The fact is that I have to compute riemannian exponentials of symmetric matrices: [Definition of the riemannian exponential](https://i.stack.imgur.com/3dyOE.png).

But I get matrices with complex coefficients. How could I get rid of that ?

Note: Even with the aforementioned implementation, I get matrices with complex numbers.

I also tried to explore the `geomstats` package, but I do not know how to use it :

https://geomstats.github.io/geometry.html#module-geomstats.geometry.spd_matrices

Thanks a lot

**Edit 1: my code and what I expect:**

This is my function:

```py
def expNearestSPD(Y, Delta):

    """
    Implementation of riemannian exponential using the nearestPD function
    I try to always keep SPD matrices
    But at the end it does not work
    """

    Y2 = nearestPD(Y)

    mul = np.matmul(  np.matmul(inv(sqrtm(Y2)), Delta), inv(sqrtm(Y2))  ) 

    mul = nearestPD(mul)

    z1 = expm(   mul   )

    z1 = nearestPD(z1)

    z = np.matmul(   np.matmul(sqrtm(Y2), z1), sqrtm(Y2)   )

    return nearestPD(z)
```

For example, here is `P`, a SPD matrix:

```
P

array([[0.1, 0. , 0. , ..., 0. , 0. , 0. ],
       [0. , 0.1, 0. , ..., 0. , 0. , 0. ],
       [0. , 0. , 0.1, ..., 0. , 0. , 0. ],
       ...,
       [0. , 0. , 0. , ..., 0.1, 0. , 0. ],
       [0. , 0. , 0. , ..., 0. , 0.1, 0. ],
       [0. , 0. , 0. , ..., 0. , 0. , 0.1]])
```

One can check:

```
np.isrealobj(P)

True
```

But when I compute `expNearestSPD(P, P)` for example, I get:

```
expNearestSPD(P, P)

array([[0.27182818+0.j, 0.        +0.j, 0.        +0.j, ...,
        0.        +0.j, 0.        +0.j, 0.        +0.j],
       [0.        +0.j, 0.27182818+0.j, 0.        +0.j, ...,
        0.        +0.j, 0.        +0.j, 0.        +0.j],
       [0.        +0.j, 0.        +0.j, 0.27182818+0.j, ...,
        0.        +0.j, 0.        +0.j, 0.        +0.j],
       ...,
       [0.        +0.j, 0.        +0.j, 0.        +0.j, ...,
        0.27182818+0.j, 0.        +0.j, 0.        +0.j],
       [0.        +0.j, 0.        +0.j, 0.        +0.j, ...,
        0.        +0.j, 0.27182818+0.j, 0.        +0.j],
       [0.        +0.j, 0.        +0.j, 0.        +0.j, ...,
        0.        +0.j, 0.        +0.j, 0.27182818+0.j]])
```

I get complex, but very little, coefficients.

Comment: Could you post a sample matrix and expected results of what you need to get out of it? I think it will make a difference if all or only some values have complex coefficients.

Comment: Ok, I will post that. The thing is that, _in theory_, I should always keep SPD matrices. But I does not happen (don't know how python makes computations) and I get (quite close to 0) complex coefficients. I think the inversions are the cause of that. Thanks for your help.

Most of the values are complex, but the imaginary parts are close to 0.

Comment: I’m having trouble executing the code. Are expm() and sqrtm() custom functions? If so, can you post them?

Comment: They come from scipy.linalg . They are respectively the exponential and square root for matrices.

Sorry for not having precised this.

Comment: Sorry, I confused a couple of different posts I was looking at!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

In fact, using the package geomstats, I found a solution.

This is exclusively for SPD matrices.

There is a function to directly compute the riemannian exponential, and even one to compute `A**t` for `A` SPD and `t` real.

I recommend using the last version of geomstats (from GitHub).

Here, `N` is the order of the square matrices (so that their sizes are `N x N`).

```py
import geomstats.backend as gs
from geomstats.geometry.spd_matrices import SPDMatrices, SPDMetricAffine

gs.random.seed(0)
space = SPDMatrices(N)
metric = SPDMetricAffine(N)

def Exp(Y, Delta):
    return metric.exp(Delta, Y)

# for the power of a SPD matrix

gs.linalg.powerm(M, t)
```