# What is the most efficient way to calculate the eigen values of a large covariance matrix?

Tags: python, matlab, linear-algebra, numba, eigenvector

I have been trying for some days to calculate the nearest positive semi-definite matrix from a very large covariance matrix to be able to sample from it.

I have tried MATLAB for the effect, but the memory usage is insane and it always crashes eventually, no error message or log file as far as I searched. The function used for the calculation can be found here https://www.mathworks.com/matlabcentral/fileexchange/42885-nearestspd. Optimizing the function to remove intermediate matrices seemed to reduce the memory usage, but it eventually crashes much in the same way.

Found this approach for doing the calculation https://stackoverflow.com/a/63131309/18660401 and switched to Python, in hopes of finding some GPU libraries to accelerate the calculations, but it seems I cannot find an up-to-date library that suports calculating eigenvectors using the numpy function. This is the function I am using:

```
import numpy as np

def get_near_psd(A):
    C = (A + A.T)/2
    eigval, eigvec = np.linalg.eig(C)
    eigval[eigval < 0] = 0

    return eigvec.dot(np.diag(eigval)).dot(eigvec.T)
```

I am currently trying to run the same function with numba in hopes that the translation to LLVM is enough to make the calculations in reasonable time, only modified the above version to include the @jit decorator from numba.

There does not seem to be a very optimized way to do this as far as I can find on my own, so any suggestion is very appreciated to crack this.

Edit: The matrix is a two-dimensional 60416x60416 covariance matrix and it is to be used to generate new samples from the distribution of the mean and covariance matrix calculated from a set of samples using a GAN. For training purposes, samples also need to be generated from randomly sampling the distribution, which I am intending to use the function multivariate_normal from numpy for.

Comment: Can you give us some data about the size of your matrices? And how many eigenvalues do you set to zero? Since you're setting eigenvalues to zero, have you thoungt about using low-rank approximations directly instead? I think the general issue is that you seem to work with full matrices and try to find an "exact" solution to your problem, but have you considered alternatives?

Comment: It is a two dimensional 60416x60416 covariance matrix calculated from the embeddings of a set of samples. The purpose is to sample from the distribution using the mean and the covariance matrix to generate new samples using a GAN. I am trying to replicate someone else's work and this was done using the MATLAB script mentioned in my question, so also trying to be as faithful as possible to the original experiment. Adding this to the question to provide context.

Comment: Sorry if it seems that I haven't made enough search for this, but have a deadline to deliver my thesis, which includes some replication of previous work where this GAN was used.

Answer (score 0):

A very up to date library that does have these capabilities including GPU support is [pytorch](https://pytorch.org/), check out the examples on the [`torch.linalg.eig`](https://pytorch.org/docs/stable/generated/torch.linalg.eig.html#torch.linalg.eig)-function and the corresponding accelerated function [`torch.linalg.eigh`](https://pytorch.org/docs/stable/generated/torch.linalg.eigh.html#torch.linalg.eigh) for symmetric/hermitian matrices. You do have to convert these matrices from numpy to pytorch-[`tensor`](https://pytorch.org/docs/stable/tensors.html)s first to do the computation (and then convert it back), but you can definitely use it in a very similar way.

Of course also this library can't just magically give you more memory, but it is highly optimized.

Comment: Thank you very much! I'll try that and report back.

Comment: After some experimentation, it seems like the only way to make this work would be to paralellize the computation over most of the GPUs I have available, but cannot seem to find a way to do it.

Comment: I don't know whether it would make sense to distribute this problem across multiple gpus. (I'm not aware of any libraries that lets you do this.)