# Generating 50 random 2x2 matrices with positive eigenvalues/positive definite matrices

Tags: python, numpy

I was wondering how I can generate about 50 random 2x2 symmetrical positive definite matrices in PYTHON. Is there a block of code using scikit or numpy anyone can guide me to?

Comment: For any matrix A, the matrix A*A is positive semidefinite, https://stackoverflow.com/questions/619335/a-simple-algorithm-for-generating-positive-semidefinite-matrices ..

Comment: The question is about positive *definite* matrices, though.

Comment: A symmetric matrix is positive definite iff all its eigenvalues are positive. Why not make a random diagonal matrix with positive diagonal?

Answer (score 1):

Strictly diagonally dominant matrices are positive definite. So you could generate a random A, compute `AA= A'A` and then increase the elements on the diagonal to make sure that

`AA[i,i] > sum( abs(AA[i,j]), j != i )`,

e.g., compute the sum on the right-hand side and then add 1 to it and assign the result to `AA[i,i]`.

More simply, you could compute `A'A + alpha*I` for some `alpha > 0` of your choice and where I is the
identity matrix. All eigenvalues of this matrix are `>= alpha`, which make it "safely" *positive definite*.

You can also use sklearn to do it easier and then make matrix values random.
See: https://scikit-learn.org/stable/modules/generated/sklearn.datasets.make_spd_matrix.html

Answer (score 1):

A real symmetric 2-by-2 matrix

```
/ a b \
\ b c /
```

is positive definite iff its trace and determinant are positive.
As the determinant is `ac-b^2` this happens iff `a` and `c` are positive and `-m < b < m` where `m` is the geometric mean `\sqrt ac`.

You can therefore draw positive `a` and `c` and a factor `f` with `-1<f<1` and then use

```
/     a         f * sqrt(ac) \
\ f * sqrt(ac)      c        /
```

Note that this method can easily be vectorized.

Answer (score 0):

"Random" means different things to different people but I'll take a stab.

As a previous answer noted, a real matrix `X` is positive semi-definite if (and only if) it can be factored as `X=M'M`, i.e. it is a Gram matrix.

One simple way to make `X` random, while also guaranteeing positive definiteness, is to use random normal entries for `M`. See also, the [Wishart distribution](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Wishart_distribution).